# python "import package as" strange behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this file strtucture:

```
mainfolder
    package/
        __init__.py
        packagefile.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
import packagefile as othername
```

If I `import package` from mainfolder, `package` will have `packagefile` and `othername` too. What is happening ? Is it imported twice ? I have python 2.7.3. Is this the expected behaviour ? When I do `import sys as something_else`, sys will not be present on the current namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. Basically the package always has the modules inside it defined. What you're doing is also importing one of those modules as another name. This doesn't prevent it from already being defined as it's original name.

I don't believe this has any untoward negative consequences. For example, were you to enter the interactive terminal you should see this:

```
>>> package.packagefile is package.othername
True
```

This indicates they are references to the same object - similar to comparing two pointers in C++, for example.

However, if you're just trying to rename a module member, I suggest simply renaming the file instead.

Comment: but when I remove the `import` statement from `__init__.py` and `import package` that way, packagefile will not be imported either. So what is `__init__.py` good for ?

Comment: `__init__.py` is still neccesary to designate the folder as a package. You can get packagefile two ways - `import package.packagefile` and access by `package.packagefile`, or `from package import packagefile` and access by `packagefile`

Comment: You should also read up on the official Python modules documentation - http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html - there's a lot of nuances and different ways to do things that I couldn't get into here.

Comment: Based on your explanation I tried to `import packagefile` with `__init__.py` removed, and then I got it; you cannot import from a folder without `__init__.py`, because it's not a package !
NOW I GET IT, thanks ! :)